# Received memory warning in Ipad1

Tags: ios

I am developing a game for Ipad.In my Ipad1 game crashes after receiving low memory warning.
After using Instruments came to know that Live Bytes of app around 6 M.B. consistently.
How to solve this issue give me any suggestion.
(will app crash if i am allocating bulk of images upto 5 mb suddenly in my app).Thanks.

Comment: How are you storing your images?  If you're not using NSCache, you might try switching to that.

Answer (score 0):

iPad 1 has 256 MB RAM - half that of any other model (and 1/4 that of modern models). So either rule out the iPad 1 by requiring a system that it cannot run, or else be very very careful when loading images. You probably don't really need images as large as what you are loading.

Also, note that a low memory warning and a crash are two different things. The low memory warning means "release some memory now!" You can perhaps prevent the crash by doing that.